# How can I write this sed/bash command in awk or perl (or python, or ...)?

Tags: perl, bash, scripting, sed, awk

I need to replace instances of `Progress (n,m)` and `Progress label="some text title" (n,m)` in a scripting language with new values `(N,M)` where

```
N= integer ((n/m) * normal)
M= integer ( normal )
```

The progress statement can be anywhere on the script line (and worse, though not with current scripts, split across lines).

The value `normal` is a specified number between 1 and 255, and `n` and `m` are floating point numbers

So far, my `sed` implementation is below.  It only works on `Progress (n,m)` formats and not `Progress label="Title" (n,m)` formats, *but its just plain nuts*:

```
#!/bin/bash
normal=$1; 
file=$2
for n in $(sed -rn '/Progress/s/Progress[ \t]+\(([0-9\. \t]+),([0-9\. \t]+)\).+/\1/p' "$file" )
do 
    m=$(sed -rn "/Progress/s/Progress[ \t]+\(${n},([0-9\. \t]+).+/\1/p" "$file")
    N=$(echo "($normal * $n)/$m" | bc)
    M=$normal
    sed -ri "/Progress/s/Progress[ \t]+\($n,$m\)/Progress ($N,$M)/" "$file"
done
```

Simply put: **This works, but, is there a better way?**

My toolbox has `sed` and `bash` scripting in it, and not so much `perl`, `awk` and the like which I think this problem is more suited to.

**Edit** Sample input.

```
Progress label="qt-xx-95" (0, 50) thermal label "qt-xx-95" ramp(slew=.75,sp=95,closed) Progress (20, 50) Pause  5 Progress (25, 50) Pause  5 Progress (30, 50) Pause  5 Progress (35, 50) Pause  5 Progress (40, 50) Pause  5 Progress (45, 50) Pause  5 Progress (50, 50)
Progress label="qt-95-70" (0, 40) thermal label "qt-95-70" hold(sp=70)        Progress (10, 40) Pause  5 Progress (15, 40) Pause  5 Progress (20, 40) Pause  5 Progress (25, 40) Pause  5
```

Comment: Could you provide sample input and expected output, please? It would be much more simple to work with.

Comment: It sounds like you're going to need a full-fledged parser in the future, so maybe it's time to pick up one of the programming languages. I recommend Python, but that's just me.

Comment: @mugenkenichi Added sample input.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams I wrote the script parser in lex/yacc; but the client doesn't want me changing the code.

Comment: @Jamie please clarify.. You have a parser that works, and they want changes to the output, but won't let you modify the parser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`awk` has good splitting capabilities, so it might be a good choice for this problem.

Here is a solution that works for the supplied input, let's call it `update_m_n_n.awk`. Run it like this in bash: `awk -f update_m_n_n.awk -v normal=$NORMAL input_file`.

```awk
#!/usr/bin/awk

BEGIN {
  ORS = RS = "Progress"
  FS = "[)(]"
  if(normal == 0) normal = 10
}

NR == 1 { print }

length > 1 { 
  split($2, A, /, */)
  N = int( normal * A[1] / A[2] )
  M = int( normal )
  sub($2, N ", " M)
  print $0
}
```

#### Explanation

- `ORS = RS = "Progress"`: Split sections at `Progress` and include `Progress` in the output.
- `FS = "[)(]"`: Separate fields at parenthesis.
- `NR == 1 { print }`: Insert `ORS` before the first section.
- `split($2, A, /, */)`: Assuming there is only on parenthesized item between occurrences of `Progress`, this splits `m` and `n` into the `A` array.
- `sub($2, N ", " M)`: Substitute the new values the into current record.

Answer (score 1):

This is somewhat brittle but it seems to do the trick? It could be changed to a one-line with perl -pe but I think this is clearer:

```
use 5.16.0;
my $normal = $ARGV[0];
while(<STDIN>){
        s/Progress +(label=\".+?\")? *( *([0-9. ]+) *, *([0-9. ]+) *)/sprintf("Progress $1 (%d,%d)", int(($2/$3)*$normal),int($normal))/eg;
        print $_;
```

}

The basic idea is to optionally capture the label clause in $1, and to capture n and m into $2 and $3. We use perl's ability to replace the matched string with an evaluated piece of code by providing the "e" modifier.  It's going to fail dramatically if the label clause has any escaped quotes or contains the string that matches something that looks like a Progress toekn, so its not ideal. I agree that you need an honest to goodness parser here, though you could modify this regex to correct some of the obvious deficiencies like the weak number matching for n and m.

Answer (score 0):

My initial thought was to try `sed` with recursive substitutions (`t` command), however I suspected that would get stuck.

This `perl` code might work for statements that are not split across lines. For splits across lines, perhaps it makes sense to write a separate pre-processor to join disparate lines.

The code splits "Progress" statements into separate line-segments, applies any replacement rules then rejoins the segments into one line and prints. Non-matching lines are simply printed. The matching code uses back-references and becomes somewhat unreadable. I have assumed your "normal" parameter can take floating values as the spec didn't seem clear.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;

die("Wrong arguments") if (@ARGV != 2);
my ($normal, $file) = @ARGV;
open(FILE, '<', $file) or die("Cannot open $file");

while (<FILE>) {
    chomp();
    my $line = $_;

    # Match on lines containing "Progress"
    if (/Progress/) {

        $line =~ s/(Progress)/\n$1/go;    # Insert newlines on which to split
        my @segs = split(/\n/, $line);    # Split line into segments containing possibly one "Progress" clause

        # Apply text-modification rules
        @segs = map {
            if (/(Progress[\s\(]+)([0-9\.]+)([\s,]+)([0-9\.]+)(.*)/) {
                my $newN = int($2/$4 * $normal);
                my $newM = int($normal);
                $1 . $newN . $3 . $newM . $5;
            } elsif (/(Progress\s+label="[^"]+"[\s\(]+)([0-9\.]+)([\s,]+)([0-9\.]+)(.*)/) {
                my $newN = int($2/$4 * $normal);
                my $newM = int($normal);
                $1 . $newN . $3 . $newM . $5;
            } else {
                $_;    # Segment doesn't contain "Progress"
            }
        } @segs;

        $line = join("", @segs);    # Reconstruct the single line
    }

    print($line,"\n");    # Print all lines
}
```